# I have an existing solution in Visual Studio 2013. How do I import it to my VS Online workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I recently upgraded to VS Community 2013 and created my Visual Studio Online account.

I have connected VS to the account but I don't know how to import my local solution (which contains 5 projects) to the VS Online account.

Comment: Simply open the solution in VS2013 Community? The online thing is not for having your code "in the cloud", I think. It is just for...I don't know. I use VS2013 without being logged on and did not think I missed something yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Make sure your source control plugin is set to Visual Studio Team Foundation server (Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in selection)
2. Connect Visual Studio with your Visual Studio Online account in the Team Explorer. (Open Team Explorer: View > Team Explorer). You will need the your VSO url (usually [your selected name].visualstudio.com
3. Open your solution and add solution to source control (right click the solution in the solution explorer and select Add solution to source control)